# C++ Calling Private Data Members in a Vector Class

Tags: c++

I'm looking to create a class that's in the form of a standard vector. I've been writing some programs with classes that have implemented Sets and not vectors, so I'm a little confused.

Here's my class:

```
class Employee
{

private:

  Struct Data
  {
unsigned Identification_Number;
// Current capacity of the set

unsigned Department_Code;
// Department Code of employee

unsigned Salary;
// Salary of employee

str Name;
// Name of employee
  }
```

If I want to call the private data members later on, can I just do the following?

```
vector<Employee> Example;

//Assume there's data in Example

cout << Example[0].Identification_Number;
cout << Example[3].Salary;
```

If not, what would be an apprpriate container? Would a list of a list be better for handling this set of data?

Comment: Why make the `struct` private when you want it publicly available? Or is `Struct Data {` a typo?

Comment: And why even have the `Data` structure in the first place? Why not place all of `Data`'s members directly in the `Employee` class?

Comment: The container here is totally irrelevant, you seem to be simply confused about how to access private members altogether. The answer is, of course, that you're not suppose to; that's the whole point.

Comment: Ahh Sorry. I see where I went wrong. I was used to making nodes like Data in my previous programs. I'll probably either end up changing those private data members to be public or using functions to call them

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the code you provide as-is, but with a few modifications you can make it work:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    unsigned GetID() const               { return Identification_Number; }
    unsigned GetDepartment() const       { return Department_Code; }
    unsigned GetSalary() const           { return Salary; }
    // Assuming you're using std::string for strings
    const std::string& GetString() const { return string; }
private:
    unsigned Identification_Number; // Current capacity of the set
    unsigned Department_Code;       // Department Code of employee
    unsigned Salary;                // Salary of employee
    string Name;                    // Name of employee
};
```

Note that the `Data` structure is totally superfluous in this case as you've presented. I've just placed all the data members within the `Employee` class itself as private data members for [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Then you can access them this way:

```
std::vector<Employee> Example; //Assume there's data in Example
// ...
cout << Example[0].GetID();
cout << Example[3].GetSalary();
```

Presumably you will set the individual variables to their correct values within the `Employee` class somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A common way is accessor functions:

```
#include <iostream>

class Employee
{
public:
    void setID(unsigned id)
    {
        Identificaiton_Number = id;
    }

    unsigned getID()
    {
        return Identificaiton_Number;
    }

private:
    unsigned Identification_Number;
    // Current capacity of the set

    unsigned Department_Code;
    // Department Code of employee

    unsigned Salary;
    // Salary of employee

    str Name;
    // Name of employee
};

int main()
{
    Employee e;

    e.setID(5);
    std::cout << e.getID() << std::endl;
}
```

Some argue that if you have getter/setter accessors, you might as well make the member public. Others argue it's better to have getter/setter accessors, because it allows you to enforce invariants/constraints or change various implementation details.

As for accessing private members: you shouldn't do it. [It's technically possible, but don't do it.](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Struct` is a typo.

You could make the `Data` struct in `Employee` anonymous by removing the name of the struct.
This will allow you to access the data directly with `Example[0].Identification_Number` however for this to work properly you would also have to make the struct public.

Another option is to remove the struct completely and store the data directly as members of the `Employee` class.

A 3rd option would be to add `const` accessor methods to return the data from the struct.